# React props to child component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've use my app global state in a component with mapStateToProps . My question is which is the best way to use props . By doing mapStateToProps in parent , get the props and then passing to the child or to do the mapStateToProps in the child .

I'm doing some optimization when my react components should update or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a redux question, right? If you can isolate a slice of state to a component subtree then you probably want to connect that slice of state to the root of that subtree so that ancestor components and siblings don't have to re-render every time it does. It also makes it easier to get the necessary props to the component in question (without worrying about passing them through all intermediate components.) See [reactjs/redux#419](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/419) for more.

Comment: This was exactly the answer i was searching for. Thank you.

Comment: Great, thanks. I updated the answer with a but more info.